# How to get x:Name value runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, gridviewcolumn

I got:

```
   <ListView.View GridViewColumnHeader.Click="ColumnHeaderClick">
      <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="Col" Header="Item">   



   private void ColumnHeaderClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        GridViewColumnHeader headerClicked = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader;

     }
```

Now, how to get the x:Name value of GridViewColumn in the method? I can't put 'Name' property for the column in xaml, and it comes like empty string in runtime. Although I am able to get the header, still need to get x:Name value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `x:Name` syntax on an element that isn't a `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement`, it registers the element with a `NameScope`.  Unfortunately, you can't retrieve the name for an element, the lookup only works the other way around.

If you need to pass additional information about the DataGridColumn, a custom attached property would be an easy way of doing it.

More information about [x:Name can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx).  Also, the [NameScope documentation describes its behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage reflection to grab the value with:

```
GridViewColumnHeader headerClicked = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader;
String xName = (String)headerClicked.getType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(headerClicked, null);
```