# Determine element name based on touch event

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

How can I determine the element name,other properties, based on the touch event given by,

```
Touch.FrameReported += new TouchFrameEventHandler(OnFrameReported);

private void OnFrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    TouchPoint primaryTouchPoint = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(null);

    TouchPointCollection points = e.GetTouchPoints(null);

    foreach (TouchPoint point in points)
    {
        if (point.Action == TouchAction.Down)
```

So far I have tried, `point.TouchDevice.DirectlyOver` but that only gives me the element type (`shape`,`button`, etc). I want to figure out the `x:name`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve the x:Name value at runtime. See this similar SO post.

[How to get x:Name value runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526357/how-to-get-xname-value-runtime)

EDIT:
However, having said that, TouchPoint.TouchDevice.DirectlyOver is a UIElement which can be cast to a FrameworkElement which has the Name property. You could use the Name property instead of the x:Name property and get your information that way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that should work try it and let me know ^^

```
string name = sender.GetType().Name;
```

Hope i helped you with this ^^

Comment: I will try it when I have a chance, I am away currently. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason, the sender is `null` when dealing with such events.